# SQL update query taking long time after column size increase

Tags: sql, parameters, sql-update, sniffing

I have a problem where an update query is taking 10 minutes to update a single table record, when it used to take milliseconds. The problem was caused by changing a varchar column in the target table [PieceNumber] from (25) to (100). The variable being used in the update statement is still declared as a varchar(25). When I run a profiler, I can see the query doing a select * from [PieceTable] instead of the update against the single record. The update statement does include the primary key. I was able to fix it by converting the variable to also be (100) in the update statement, but my question is why is it performing differently based on the variable length?

Tried to rebuild indexes and updated statistics with full scan. Also a side note is that it's calling this across a linked server.

```
DECLARE @NEWBARCODE VARCHAR(25) = 'ABCD'
DECLARE @ID INT = 1

UPDATE [LinkedServer].[DB].[dbo].[PieceTable] 
SET [PieceNumber] = @NEWBARCODE, -- CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @NEWBARCODE)
    [Date] = GETDATE()
WHERE [PieceID] = @ID
```

In the above query, if I replace the @NEWBARCODE line with the convert code thats commented out - it works as expected. The [PieceNumber] column in the table [PieceTable] is the column that was updated from (25) to a length of (100)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) after the WHERE clause if you will be using @ID variable instead of a numeric constant.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tried that as well with no luck